# ImageView not taking the right amout of pixels in screen

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I might be missing something really obvious but problem is I need to put 3 images of the same size aligned horizontally in the layout. Since my primary test device is a nexus5 and I want to avoid pixelation I divided the device's horizontal resolution (1080 pixels) by 3... so 360pixels for each image. However, when I source the first image it takes the whole width of the screen, as if the the width of the screen is 360 pixels or less. Why does this happen?

Here the xml of the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/one_circle"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the size of your screen by:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

then , if they 3 in same size -

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image.setX(0); // set it at starting
image2.setX(image.getX()+image.getWidth()); setting it as first image starting X + Width = end of it.
image3.setX(image2.getX()+image2.getWidth());  same like the previous one.
```

This should work in any android device, not just yours. I haven't checked it so you maybe will need to fix something. good luck